# Create a blank copy of each file in directory, with a different extension

Tags: shell, terminal, command

How can I create a blank .XXX extension for each file in a directory in Ubuntu terminal?  I know how to change extensions of current files, but I don't know how I can create copies with different extensions.

Answer (score 0):

[Assuming you are using bash]

Inside the directory you want:

```
for f in $(ls); do
    touch "${f}.XXX"
done
```